# Admob Error onAdFailedToLoad Intersticial

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

Llevo una semana intentando solucionar el problema y no lo he
conseguido, he creado mi primera app en android studio y al añadir los
anuncios intersticiales me aparece el error 3 de onAdFailedToLoad. He
leido que es problema de que no me devuelven los anuncios desde los
servidores de admob pero voy a adjuntar mi codigo por si hubiera
escrito algo mal. 
Este el codigo de mi manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package=""> //Nombre del package

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
                android:value="ID APP"/>

        <activity android:name="(Nombre de package).BatallaBorrachos">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="(Nombre de package).PantallaJuego">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="(Nombre de package).EleccionPregunta">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="(Nombre de package).MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Dentro de metadata en el value introduje el id de aplicacion que me proporciona admob.

el archivo de build gradle (project) :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build gradle (app) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "" //Mi nombre de package
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.1"
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Por ultimo los metodos que inicializan la publicidad y que muestran el instersticial:

```
 fun inicilizarPubli(){

      MobileAds.initialize(this, "ID de la aplicacion de admob")
      if(ronda == 3 || ronda == 5){
          mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
          mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ID del intersticial"
          mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
          mInterstitialAd.adListener = object : AdListener() {
              override fun onAdLoaded() {
                  toast("OK")
              }

              override fun onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode: Int) {
                  toast("ERROR $errorCode")
              }
          }
      }

    }

    fun cargarPubli() {

        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
            mInterstitialAd.show()

        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.")
        }

    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, es importante revises el LogCat , al desplegarse el mensaje "onAdFailedToLoad Intersticial" debe mostrarse más información que indica el problema. Por  cierto te invito a revisar [ask] y realiza el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Perdon si he formulado mal el titulo, el error que me sale es al ejecutar la aplicacion con el dispositivo movil ya que me devuelve el valor constante 3 de la funcion onAdFailedToLoad que segun he leido es un problema que surje cuando los de admob no te envian ningun anuncio para mostrar por tanto no hay logcat, porque es una aplicacion subida al play store. he de decir que en el emulador de android studio si que muestra el anuncio de prueba

Comment: me paso algo parecido.. tenía una app desarrollada con Eclipse subida a Google Play, en la cual la publicidad funciona perfectamente. Migré la app a Android Studio y seguí los pasos para añadir publicidad, por más que lo intenté siempre me saltaba el error 3, incluso añadí campañas de terceros con Mediación, y seguía el saltando el mismo error.
Volví a Eclipse, actualicé mi App a lo último, compilé y funcionaba perfectamente la publicidad. Así que mi App con publicidad sigo desarrollándola en eclipse, no me queda otra.